# Autocrop an image in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I need to autocrop images in Codename One.
Autocrop an image means to remove the borders from that image. The purpose of the following code is to search for the largest possible border area that is all the same color (or transparency), and then crops this area from the image.

To better understand the algorithm that I wrote, please consider the following picture *(take attention to who are topx, topy, bottomx, bottomy)*:
[image]

This is my code. Could you help me to understand what is wrong and to fix it? It doesn't work as expected, as reported by the logs and by the screenshot:

```
Image arrowDownIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_DROP_DOWN, "Color-Gray", 30);
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER));
hi.getToolbar().hideToolbar();
hi.getContentPane().setUIID("NoMarginNoPadding");
hi.add(new Label(getAutoCroppedImage(arrowDownIcon), "NoMarginNoPadding"));
hi.show();
```

CSS

```
#Constants {
    includeNativeBool: true; 
}

NoMarginNoPadding {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1pt blue solid;
}
```

```
    /**
     * Autocrop an image, using as base color the pixel at top left
     *
     * @param source
     * @return
     */
    public static Image getAutoCroppedImage(Image source) {
        if (source == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ImageUtilities.getCroppedImage -> null source image");
        }
        if (source instanceof FontImage) {
            source = ((FontImage) source).toImage();
        }

        int[] pixels = source.getRGB(); // array instance containing the ARGB data within this image

        // Get top-left pixel color as "baseline" for cropping (it can be any color or transparent)
        int baseColor = pixels[0];

        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        int topy = 0;
        int topx = 0;
        int bottomy = height - 1;
        int bottomx = width - 1;

        // Search for topy, iterating the pixels from top to bottom
        for (int y = 0; y < height && topy == 0; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                if (pixels[y * width + x] == baseColor) {
                    topy = y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Search for topx, interating the pixels from left to right
        for (int x = 0; x < width && topx == 0; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                if (pixels[y * width + x] == baseColor) {
                    topx = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Search for bottomy, iterating from bottom to top
        for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0 && bottomy == height - 1; y--) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                if (pixels[y * width + x] == baseColor) {
                    bottomy = y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Search for bottomx, interating from right to left
        for (int x = width - 1; x >= 0 && bottomx == width - 1; x--) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                if (pixels[y * width + x] == baseColor) {
                    bottomx = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Image destination = Image.createImage((bottomx - topx), (bottomy - topy), 0);

        Log.p("Original width: " + width, Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Original height: " + height, Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Cropped width: " + destination.getWidth(), Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Cropped height: " + destination.getHeight(), Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Top-left point cropped image: (" + topx + "," + topy + ")", Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Bottom-right point cropped image: (" + bottomx + "," + bottomy + ")", Log.DEBUG);

        Graphics graphics = destination.getGraphics();
        graphics.drawImage(source, topx, topy, destination.getWidth(), destination.getHeight());

        return destination;
    }
```

Logs:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,120 - Original width: 529
[EDT] 0:0:0,120 - Original height: 529
[EDT] 0:0:0,120 - Cropped width: 526
[EDT] 0:0:0,120 - Cropped height: 526
[EDT] 0:0:0,120 - Top-left point cropped image: (1,1)
[EDT] 0:0:0,120 - Bottom-right point cropped image: (527,527)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation of a baseline color don't fit with the realities of how images work. This is especially true for JPEG which can have a variety of "white" colors and for which you will need a threshold. But it's also true to some degree for lossless image formats like PNG  where values like alpha can behave "oddly" e.g. a valid PNG file can return 0x00ffffff and 0x0 for two pixels and still be valid!

This happens when the drawing app has some transparent content, most artists can't tell the difference and the app doesn't discard that non-visible data. So you need to add explicit tests for alpha e.g.:

```
if ((pixels[y * width + x] == baseColor || (pixels[y * width + x] & 0xff000000) == 0) { 
     ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shai, you gave me right hints. My code had also other mistakes: I added a new answer with my code fully fixed, hoping that it can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

[Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764452/2670744) gave me right hints. However my code has also other two mistakes: the first one is that the comparison should be `color != baseColor` instead of `color == baseColor`; the second one is that the parameters to draw the new image should be `graphics.drawImage(source, -topx, -topy);` and not the ones that I wrote.

The thresholds, in my use case, are not necessary, however for anyone who wants to implement them I suggest to use the Codename One `ColorUtil` API than the bitwise comparator to get the alpha, red, green and blue, because that API is a lot more readable and intuitive than the bitwise comparator.

This is my fixed method, I also add a screenshot to demostrate how it works:

```
    /**
     * Autocrop an image, using as base color the pixel at top left
     *
     * @param source
     * @return
     */
    public static Image getAutoCroppedImage(Image source) {
        if (source == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ImageUtilities.getCroppedImage -> null source image");
        }
        if (source instanceof FontImage) {
            source = ((FontImage) source).toImage();
        }

        int[] pixels = source.getRGB(); // array instance containing the ARGB data within this image

        // Get top-left pixel color as "baseline" for cropping (it can be any color or transparent)
        int baseColor = pixels[0];

        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        int topy = 0;
        int topx = 0;
        int bottomy = height - 1;
        int bottomx = width - 1;

        // Search for topy, iterating the pixels from top to bottom
        for (int y = 0; y < height && topy == 0; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int color = pixels[y * width + x];
                int alpha = ColorUtil.alpha(color);
                if (color != baseColor && alpha != 0) {
                    topy = y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Search for topx, interating the pixels from left to right
        for (int x = 0; x < width && topx == 0; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int color = pixels[y * width + x];
                int alpha = ColorUtil.alpha(color);
                if (color != baseColor && alpha != 0) {
                    topx = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Search for bottomy, iterating from bottom to top
        for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0 && bottomy == height - 1; y--) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int color = pixels[y * width + x];
                int alpha = ColorUtil.alpha(color);
                if (color != baseColor && alpha != 0) {
                    bottomy = y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Search for bottomx, interating from right to left
        for (int x = width - 1; x >= 0 && bottomx == width - 1; x--) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int color = pixels[y * width + x];
                int alpha = ColorUtil.alpha(color);
                if (color != baseColor && alpha != 0) {
                    bottomx = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Image destination = Image.createImage((bottomx - topx), (bottomy - topy), 0);

        Log.p("Original width: " + width, Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Original height: " + height, Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Cropped width: " + destination.getWidth(), Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Cropped height: " + destination.getHeight(), Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Top-left point cropped image: (" + topx + "," + topy + ")", Log.DEBUG);
        Log.p("Bottom-right point cropped image: (" + bottomx + "," + bottomy + ")", Log.DEBUG);

        Graphics graphics = destination.getGraphics();
        graphics.drawImage(source, -topx, -topy);

        return destination;
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image: Autocrop an image in Codename One]

Comment: I edit my answer fixing another mistake. Now it should be ok.